# SWIFT: 2 custom cell in tableview. What's wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I want to put 2 custom cell in `TableView`, but I have a small problem with it. I tried to find answer in Google and StackOverflow, but answers can't help me.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FistCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        //set cell2
    }
    if indexPath.row >= 1{
        var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        let cons = aArray[indexPath.row - 1]
        // set cell2 
    }
    return cell // (!) Use of unresolved identifier "cell"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "2 custom cell"?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I mean that I want to have two different type of custom cell in tableview

Comment: @Maxim Globak Please specify what do you want in each cell to get more information, and please show your **CustomCell** class

Comment: If you want two different types of custom cells, why are you dequeueing the same class, CustomCell, both times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to draw the cell declaration outside:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  var cell: CustomCell!
  if indexPath.row == 0{
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FistCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
    //set cell2
  }
  if indexPath.row >= 1{
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
    let cons = aArray[indexPath.row - 1]
    // set cell2 
  }
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Individually, everything works, the cell is described in the right class, but when I tried to connect all, I have failed.

Comment: It's out of scope when you declare it inside the `if` statements

Comment: In this case: where "return cell" // (!) variable "Cell" used before being initialized

Comment: Bloody Swift. Just give it an init like `var cell = CustomCell()` or use an optional. See my added "!"

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have a similar requirement in my project, need to display 2 different cells in a table. I am trying to show them by defining 2 prototypes in a table. but it is not working. This is the link that I have followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift

Comment: @ThomasKilian could you please guide me

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have posted a query. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515763/how-to-show-2-customized-cells-in-the-uitableview

Comment: @Dee The whole process is quite complex and I needed a couple of YT tutorials first. Finally I reduced the TableViewPlayground example from Apple to the minimum I needed. Once I grasped that I started creating a simple sandbox on my own to play around.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the cell out of the if statement.