# how to change cell identifier programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Sorry but I really new in this case.

I have a project where I use `revealViewController`. And inside this project I have `UITableView` with 4 prototype cells within where each cell shows the user another `UIView` by segue. Every cell has its own identifier, for example: cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4.

In code I implement an array that must contain the same strings of names of the cells to work properly:

```
array = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"]
```

And everything is working fine, in first row of the `UITableView` I see "cell1", on second row - "cell2" and etc.

But now I want to localize my app and I want to change names of these 4 rows according to the language of the user/application. The problem is that names must be equals to cell identifier. So no if I change a name neither I change an identifier separately I've got `SIGART` error.

So, my question is what should I do? Should I change cell identifier in code due `NSLocalizedString`? Or there is another solution?
Thank to everyone in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing the purpose of a cell identifier. The identifier is so the dequeing process can properly identify what type of cell you want to use. In other words, if you have 3 different "types" of cells, they'll have 3 identifiers. If your cells are exactly the same just use one identifier.

Comment: Make a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`: you could add the properties you need to keep reference as well as text (e.g. a `UILabel` in your custom cell class) or other objects in your custom cells.

Comment: Thank you for advise. I use that code dequeuing my 4 cells: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableArray[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell where TableArray is like the array I wrote above. And it works fine till I want to localise the names

Comment: I would avoid making an implementation detail, such as reuseIdentifiers, visible to the user. You should update your logic to use a fixed reuseIdentifier and then get a localized string for display from another source.

Comment: Thank's to everyone guys!  I found a way to my solution in that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift.  Now it works fine for me))))