# NSTableView with two custom table cell views alternating per row (MacOS)

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

I have a single column, view-based NSTableView in which I want to place two different custom cell views, one alternating with the other in each row, like so:

Odd rows: `OddRowNumberCellView`.
Even rows: `EvenRowNumberCellView`.

There a solution for iOS from Natasha in her highly rated answer [UITableview with more than One Custom Cells with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift/30776750#30776750) but it depends on the Dynamic Prototypes setting in the Attributes Inspector, a feature that is not available for MacOS.

Does anyone know how to do this on Mac please? (I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do exactly the same but instead of Dynamic Protoypes you set an Identifier "OddRow" or "EvenRow" and then in your datasource implementation:

```
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
   let cellView: tableView.make(withIdentifier: "EvenRow")
   //set the data here
   return cellView
} else {
   let cellView: tableView.make(withIdentifier: "OddRow")
   //set the data here
   return cellView
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for that, Oskar. I'm a happy bunny!