# How to give more than 2 custom cell on one tableView for chat

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, chat, custom-cell

chat image for chat ui have 3 type which is text , image , and carousel . am i need to make 3 custom cell for one tableView and how to do that ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVt9j.png]

Comment: same as you do for single cell

Comment: Hope this will help you [UITableview with more than One Custom Cells with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift)

Comment: hi , thanks for answer . i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to create three custom cell, for crousal either use third party or a collection view inside tableview cell.

for eg:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cellIncomming = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IncommingChatCell") as! IncommingChatCell
  let cellOutgoing = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OutgoingChatCell") as! OutgoingChatCell

  let chatInfo = chatDataSourse[indexPath.row]
  if chatInfo.user == "receiver" {
    cellIncomming.chatLabel.text = chatInfo.chatString
    return cellIncomming
  }else {
    cellOutgoing.chatLabel.text = chatInfo.chatString
    return cellOutgoing
  }
}
```

Comment: hi , i have one question .

Comment: how if my response from api no have sender or receiver

Comment: {
    "result": {
        "output": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Ini respons berbentuk teks",
                "speech": "Ini respons berbentuk teks"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Ini adalah teks yang dipakai sebagai dummy response untuk message type text",
                "speech": "Ini adalah teks yang dipakai sebagai dummy response untuk message type text"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Hi @amaulana tell your backend guys to provide anything(eg: userId or the sender/receiver etc), so that you can recognize that the chat comes from which side. In the above json i can not see any way to set chat bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

in cellforrow

```
if Condition1 {
    let cell : CellOne! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "CellOne") as? CellOne
    return cell
}else if Condition2{
    let cell : CellTwo! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "CellTwo") as? CellTwo
    return cell
}else{
    let cell : CellThree! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "CellThree") as? CellThree
    return cell
}
```