# How to specify for chat which have 3 type like Text , Image and Carousel , and our send text also show on chat

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, chat

[image: chat image]

my case is i need to specify my chat is from me or from response to make left and right chat . and my response chat also have 3 type of chat like text , image , and carousel.
the problem is my response don't have sender / receiver to specify where is our chat , and where is chat response .

```
resolvequery is our send chat to api

i have make 2 custom cell for specifying my send chat and my response chat
```

this is my response

```
{
    "resolvequery": "text",
    "statuscode": 200,
    "timestamp": {
        "date": "2019-02-06 10:50:26.785700",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "result": {
        "output": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Ini respons berbentuk teks",
                "speech": "Ini respons berbentuk teks"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Ini adalah teks yang dipakai sebagai dummy response untuk message type text",
                "speech": "Ini adalah teks yang dipakai sebagai dummy response untuk message type text"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give more than 2 custom cell on one tableView for chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642655/how-to-give-more-than-2-custom-cell-on-one-tableview-for-chat)

Comment: noo its different . this question is for specifying chat type from me and from response

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your code architecture.

In all cases, the chat view on the right is the sender ( myself ), so logically, API should either give a boolean element that states if `received` or basically pass the sender user id with every chat text element, and check if the user id is equal to the current logged in id ( this means chat is sent and set to right), and if not then it should be on left.