# How to create array of types Swift

Tags: swift

So, my thought are:

I have different classes of UITableViewCell: CustomCell1, CustomCell2, CustomCell3

I have UITableView, and I need to add them through cellForRowAt, but there can be multiple cell of any type.

For example, table should contain this: CustomCell2, CustomCell2, CustomCell3, CustomCell1, CustomCell1, also there is Bool variable, and if it's true, them CustomCell1 should be added, if not then CustomCell3

Is there any way of creating array of this cell types? Like

```
arrayOfTypes = [CustomCell2, CustomCell2, CustomCell3, CustomCell1, CustomCell1, boolVariable ? CustomCell1 : CustomCell3]
```

So then in cellForRowAt I can call like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let type = arrayOfTypes[indexPath.row]
        switch type {
        case is CustomCell1:
        ...
        case is CustomCell2:
        ...
        case is CustomCell3:
        ...
        default:
        ...
        }
}
```

Or maybe there's more convenient way of doing such a thing?

So now in project I do this:

```
enum CustomCellType {
    case CustomCell1
    case CustomCell2
    case CustomCell3
}

class CellItem {
    var cellType: CustomCellType

    init(CellType type: CustomCellType) {
        self.cellType = type
    }
}

...
class WorkingWithData: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableData = [CellItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        fillCells()
    }

    func fillCells() {
        let cellItem = CellItem(CellType: .CustomCell1)
        tableData.append(cellItem)
        let cellItem2 = CellItem(CellType: .CustomCell3)
        tableData.append(cellItem2)
    }

    ...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = tableData[indexPath.row]
        switch item.cellType {
        case .CustomCell1:
        //dequeuereusablecell
        case .CustomCell2:
        //dequeuereusablecell
        case .CustomCell3:
        //dequeuereusablecell
        default:
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableview with more than One Custom Cells with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your first question:

```
let cellTypes: [UITableViewCell.Type] = [UITableViewCell.self]
    let type = cellTypes[indexPath.row]
    switch type {
    case is UITableViewCell.Type:
        break
    default:
        break
}
```

Another way:

```
enum CustomCellType: Int {
    // enum names in swift starts with lower case
    case customCell1
    case customCell2
    case customCell3

    var dequeType: UITableViewCell.Type {
        switch self {
        case .customCell1: return CustomCellType.self
        case .customCell2: return CustomCellType2.self
        case .customCell3: return CustomCellType3.self
        }
    }
}

// Add extension to register and deque cells with type
public extension UITableView {
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_ cellType: T.Type) {
        register(cellType, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: cellType))
    }
    func dequeue<T: UITableViewCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: String(describing: cellType),
            for: indexPath
        ) as? T else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell for \(cellType)")
        }
        return cell
    }
}

// ––––––––– Inside Class where the tableview exists –––––––––
// Register cells
func registerCells() {
    CustomCellType.allCases.forEach({ tableView.register($0.dequeType) })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cellType = CustomCellType(rawValue: indexPath.row) else {
        fatalError("Your message")
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeue(cellType.dequeType, for: indexPath)
    // Cell is now with concrete type
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Samps, i implementer code with let cellTypes: [UITableViewCell.Type] = [UITableViewCell.self] , but it seems, that it doesn't work with custom types of UITableViewCell, because compiler shows me Warning:
"Cast from 'UITableViewCell.Type' to unrelated type 'CustomCell1' always fails"
in 
case is CustomCell1:

Comment: You're correct. My bad.  You need to use case is UITableViewCell.Type.
I fixed in answers also.