# How to show 2 customized cells in the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have to show 2 different cells in a table. I have tried it by setting a prototype to a table. but it is still showing `Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers` warning.

could someone please guide me to resolve this warning.

Followed this link:
[UITableview with more than One Custom Cells with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift)

Comment: instead of two different cell you can use one cell with two different view.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Yeah may be we can do that. But I am trying to know the mistake that I did using prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard you have to define the Identifier for the cells like the below image[image]

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to use the specific identifier for specific cell like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Identifier1")
        //set the data here
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Identifier2")
        //set the data here
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but I am unable to load the cell. Don't know where am I dng it wrong

Comment: @Dee Add breakpoints and check whether you are getting the object of cell or not.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the `Reuse Identifier` for both prototype cells, and they must be different. Then in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, you must dequeue the cells using the corresponding `Reuse Identifier` based on the indexPath given.

[image: Reuse Identifier]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableView {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    case 1:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    break:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```